# How do I change the image style for avatars displayed in comments

Tags: 8, comments, media

I'd like to use a custom image style for the comment avatars, but I don't know where the setting in Drupal is to change it.

I thought if I changed the user image style at `admin/config/people/accounts/display` that might work, but it doesn't. There's no image field at `admin/structure/comment/manage/comment/display`, so I can't change the style there.

I did this on a site a couple weeks ago on another site, but I can't remember for the life of me how I did it. I don't think I needed to make code modifications. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the image style used for displaying avatars in comments by editing the "compact" display mode for user accounts.

The setting can be found at */admin/config/people/accounts/display/compact*. Or by navigating the administration interface:

1. Admin -> Configuration
2. Account Settings
3. 'Manage display' tab
4. 'Compact' sub tab.
5. On the 'Picture' row, click the edit field settings button (Cog image) located on on the right.
6. Then select your image style.

Comment: Ah, there it is. I have a bad habit of missing that row of different displays on the "Manage display" tab. Thanks for the help!